Local finite dimensional algebras are $\tau$-tilting finite
Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$. If $A$ is a local algebra (has unique maximal left ideal), then it is well known that $A$ is $\tau$-tilting finite ($\tau$ being the Auslander-Reiten translate in $A$-$\mathrm{mod}$). But I can't seem to find a complete justification for it.
I think the justification that people usually give is that the only bricks (one-dimensional endomorphism algebra) are the one dimension simple module. But I don't seem to figure out why that is the case.

Why are there no other bricks?


If $M$ is a nonzero $A$-module, then $M$ has the unique simple $A$-module $S$ as a quotient and as a submodule. So there are nonzero module homomorphisms $M\to S\to M$. The composition is an endomorphism of $M$ whose image is isomorphic to $S$.
Unless $M\cong S$, this endomorphism must be a nonzero nonisomorphism, so $M$ is not a brick.
